# nmcli turning on wifi interface

Tags: wifi, wlan, nmcli

Recently I founded some problems with connecting to wifi with my bcm4312 card.

It works with nmcli tool, which sets up the device with 'nmcli radio wifi on'
Then I need to make 'dhclient wlan0' to make it works.

1. After 'pm-suspend', the connections seems disable, and repeating above commands does not work. After rebooting it goes fine.
2. I put the commands into rc.local to set this, but it does not seems to go, where should it goes to run at startup?

> ```
> #!/bin/sh -e
> #
> # rc.local
>
> nmcli radio wifi on &
>
> dhclient wlan0 &
>
> exit 0
> ```